# Counting the number of 1's on the left side of a binary representation

Tags: mips

Im trying to get the number of 1's on the left side (bits 16-31) This code seems to work but im getting 1 extra count on my 1's from certain integers.

For example:
1536 in binary is 0000 0000 0000 0000 | 0000 0110 0000 0000
and im getting 0 1's on the left side which is correct.

Also:
100000 left side binary is 0000 0000 0000 0001
and my result is 1. which is also correct.

However:
1000000000 in binary is 0011 1011 1001 1010 | 1100 1010 0000 0000
and im getting 10 1's on the left side instead of 9.

Ive tested other numbers as well but they also have an extra count.

```
#Displays number of 1's on left half
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, left
   syscall

   li $t2, 0 #i = 0
   srl $t3, $s0, 16 #shifts users number to the right by 16 bits

Counter:   
   and $t4, $t3, 1 #Mask off bit
   beq $t4, 1, Count #if mask = 1 go to count
   srl $t3, $t3, 1 #if mask != 1 (aka 0) shifts right by 1

   beq $t3, 0, Exit #once the shifted bits = 0 go to exit

Count:     
   add $t2, $t2, 1 #increment i++
   srl $t3, $t3, 1 #shifts right by 1
   j Counter       

Exit:      
   li $v0, 1 #Displays number of 1's
   move $a0, $t2
   syscall
```

Not sure if the code is even correct since im new to mips. Could be possible that the whole thing is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `clz`/`clo` to count the number of leading zeros and ones, and use that to count the number of ones. The idea is to consume the leading zeroes, then count the leading ones (shifting those bits out of the register) until the input data is zero.

i.e.:

```
  li $t1, 0x4F044321  % $t1 Input number
  srl $t1, $t1, 16
  sll $t1, $t1, 16    % Discard least significant bits
  li $t2, 0           % $t2 will hold number of 1s
count:
  beqz $t1, done    
  clz $t3, $t1
  sllv $t1, $t1, $t3
  clo $t3, $t1
  addu $t2, $t2, $t3
  sllv $t1, $t1, $t3
  b count
done:
```